# C++: template<typename T, T t> and instantiation with float

Tags: c++, templates

I have a problem, where I can not instantiate a template with the type *float*, allthough it works just fine with an *int*.

The following code shows my problem:

```
template<typename T, T v>
struct Test
{
    constexpr static T value = v;
};

int main()
{
    Test<int,   1   >::value;
    Test<float, 1.0f>::value;

    return 0;
}
```

This program compiles perfectly fine, as long only the instantiation with *int* is present - as soon as I add the second line with *float*, the compilation failes with the error: " C993: 'float': illegal type for non-type parameter 'v' ". Does anybody have an idea on how to solve the problem and make it compile with *float*?

I am using MSVC and C++17.

Sincerely,

Lehks

Comment: Floating-point types can't appear as a template parameter. That's that.

Comment: Look at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters, at the part where it list parameter list: _type is one of the following types (optionally cv-qualified, the qualifiers are ignored): (...) integral type; (...)_

Comment: Thank you very much, you two!